# vim's netrw plugin show error message:"The system cannot find the file specified." when change remote directory via FTP

Tags: vim, ftp, netrw

[image: The system cannot find the file specified]

remote ftp server is microsoft ftp.

so, i suspect that this is a bug.

can anyone knows what happend?

Comment: What command are you using to open the file?

Comment: Same problem here, also in a Microsoft Server (I just try to access and edit files in a Linux server and it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you positive the file is really available from the URI you tried?  Can you access it via your browser, with an `ftp://` URL, or from a standalone FTP client?

Comment: yes,ftp url is fine,because i can retrieve files from remote ftp server.